# rails syntax error: wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, syntax, arguments

while building a website with rails, I found a little syntax error that I really don't understand what caused it.

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_secure_password
   has_many :posts, dependent: :nullify
   has_many :comments, dependent: :nullify

   validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 30}
   validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true, format: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i


   def full_name
     (first_name +" "+ last_name).titleize
   end

 end
```

this is model file for user. If I run this file, it causes an error: wrong number of arguments(given 1, expected 0). However if I give a space like so,

```
  def full_name
     (first_name + " "+ last_name).titleize
   end
```

It runs normally.

Although I know I can just ignore it, I'm just so curious about how the space causes argument error, it ain't no argument I think..

I also ran the same code in normal ruby by making my own titleize method in string class, it works fine without the space.
so curious !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [use `ruby_parser`](https://github.com/seattlerb/ruby_parser) to eliminate your doubts about how this is actually parsed.

`RubyParser.for_current_ruby.parse '(first_name +" "+ last_name)'` results in:

```
s(:call, nil,
         :first_name,
         s(:call, s(:call, s(:str, " "),
                           :+@),
                  :+,
                  s(:call, nil,
                           :last_name)))
```

Effectively, you're getting `first_name((+" ") + last_name)`, or in a more redundant/methody fashion, `self.first_name((" ".+@).+(self.last_name))`.

Meaning there is an argument in a call of the `first_name` method, stemming from accidental use of `+@`, the unary plus, on `" "`. But since  `first_name` is an attribute getter (I guess?) and does not accept any arguments, you're getting an `ArgumentError`.

---

To help you interpret this output, a `:call` S-expression consists of:

- `:call`
- subject (a value on which a method is being called, `nil` if `self`)
- method name as a symbol
- 0 or more arguments

---

And by the way, [Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) could have warned you about this:

```
Lint/AmbiguousOperator: Ambiguous positive number operator. Parenthesize the method
arguments if it's surely a positive number operator, or add a whitespace to the
right of the + if it should be a addition.
(first_name +" "+ last_name)
            ^
```

Consider adding it into your workflow.

Comment: ooh TIL `ruby_parser` - awesome!

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining in detail! I respect your knowledge

Answer (score 2):

This is likely going between the unary-plus operator and the binary-plus operator when you put code directly next to it.

unary plus is just like unary-minus eg `-2` and I'm sure you understand the difference between writing `1 -2` and `1 - 2`?

As an aside, the standard "ruby way" would be to interpolate rather than use concatenation, so your line would be better written:

```
"#{first_name} #{last_name}".titleize
```